# Found a part on an old FM transmitter used for tuning. What is it?

Tags: radio, frequency-modulation

This is an old transmitter from the early nineties. The part is the white block with the screw through it.  I'm assuming it's a capacitor of some sort, but other than that I don't know much.  I don't have a meter to test capacitance with, which is why I'm asking for help identifying it.  Furthermore, if the part can be identified, is there something I could replace it with to make more minute adjustments to the broadcast frequency? [image: The part is the white block with the screw through it.]

Comment: This is an old-style trimmer capacitor - I don't think that style is available these days, but current styles could be substituted.  Maximum capacity is probably under 50 pF.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32020/discussion-on-question-by-furrysalamander-found-a-part-on-an-old-fm-transmitter).

Comment: **Identification Of Parts Is On Topic!**

Comment: From ops description: The part is the white block with the screw through it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Arco brand Type/Series 46 Mica Compression Trimmer Capacitor. This body style is "vintage" compared to modern day trimmer capacitor.

[Data sheet here](http://www.rf-microwave.com/datasheets/1470_ARCO_462_01.pdf).

[image]

The value is between 5 and 80 pF. Some sites say 5 to 50pF, data sheet says 462 is 10 to 80pF.

Any trimmer capacitor of similar values can be used. Ideally, one with a shaft and large turn radius for better turning/tuning.

Answer (score 2):

It's a trimmer capacitor -- likely 2-25 pF or smaller.